# LOAD DATA INFILE skipping records

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I'm trying to load data from a CSV file into a MySQL database, and noticed that a large number of records seem to be skipped when I import the file.

The data comes from a Government source, and is very oddly formatted with single quotes, etc in unusual places. Here's a sample of a record not getting inserted:

```
"'050441'","STANFORD HOSPITAL","CA","H_HSP_RATING_7_8","How do patients rate the hospital overall?","Patients who gave a rating of'7' or '8' (medium)","22","300 or more","37",""
```

This record, however, does get inserted:

```
"'050441'","STANFORD HOSPITAL","CA","H_HSP_RATING_0_6","How do patients rate the hospital overall?","Patients who gave a rating of '6' or lower (low)","8","300 or more","37",""
```

The SQL I'm using to load the data is here:

```
mysql> load data infile "c:\\HQI_HOSP_HCAHPS_MSR.csv" into table hospital_qualit
y_scores fields terminated by "," enclosed by '"' lines terminated by "\n" IGNOR
E 1 LINES;
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? It seems that only have of the records are actually being inserted correctly.

Comment: Could you please give us the definition of your table structure?

Comment: did u figure out the difference between the inserted  n failed record/

Answer (score 3):

After executing the query with failed record mentioned over here.

```
mysql> load data ....;
```

execute the foll code

```
mysql> show warnings;
```

It will show the error why the query got failed? and carry on with the next step to solve it.

I did a small test with ur data which worked fine:

```
CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `no` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `rating` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `rate_desc1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `rate_desc2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `no1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `desc3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `no2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `desc4` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

/var/lib/mysql/test/test.csv contianing both of working n non-working records:

1,"'050441'","STANFORD HOSPITAL","CA","H_HSP_RATING_7_8","How do patients rate the hospital overall?","Patients who gave a rating of'7' or '8' (medium)","22","300 or more","37",""
2,"'050441'","STANFORD HOSPITAL","CA","H_HSP_RATING_0_6","How do patients rate the hospital overall?","Patients who gave a rating of '6' or lower (low)","8","300 or more","37",""

```
mysql> load data infile "test.csv" into table test2 fields terminated by "," enclosed by '"' lines terminated by "\n" IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

**result:**
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.05 sec)

Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

> **Conclusion:** So, i think the difference is only in the datatypes of the columns n see the warnings genereated